# How to add a button to a QTreeView row

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview

I have got this code to have tabs and tree view. 
I would like that each row in a tree view would have some small buttons.
How I can add a buttons to a rows of tree view?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class tabdemo(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(tabdemo, self).__init__(parent)
      self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 300)
      self.tab1 = QWidget()
      self.tab2 = QWidget()
      self.tab3 = QWidget()


      self.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab 1")
      self.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab 2")
      self.addTab(self.tab3, "Tab 3")
      self.tab1UI()
      self.tab2UI()
      self.tab3UI()
      self.setWindowTitle("tab demo")

    def tab3UI(self):
      layout = QFormLayout()
      layout.addRow("Name", QLineEdit())
      layout.addRow("Address", QLineEdit())
      self.setTabText(0, "Contact Details")
      self.tab3.setLayout(layout)

    def tab2UI(self):
      layout = QFormLayout()
      sex = QHBoxLayout()
      sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Male"))
      sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Female"))
      layout.addRow(QLabel("Sex"), sex)
      layout.addRow("Date of Birth", QLineEdit())
      self.setTabText(1, "Personal Details")
      #self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
      self.tab2.setLayout(layout)



    def tab1UI(self):
        layout =  QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("subjects"), 0, 0) 
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Physics"), 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QCheckBox("Maths"), 0, 2)

        view = QTreeView()
        view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        model = QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
        view.setModel(model)
        view.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        # populate data
        for i in range(3):
            parent1 = QStandardItem('Family {}. Some long status text for sp'.format(i))
            parent1.setCheckable(True)
            for j in range(3):
                child1 = QStandardItem('Child {}'.format(i * 3 + j))
                child2 = QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j + 1))
                child3 = QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j + 2))
            parent1.appendRow([child1, child2, child3])
            model.appendRow(parent1)
            # span container columns
            view.setFirstColumnSpanned(i, view.rootIndex(), True)
        # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        # expand third container
        index = model.indexFromItem(parent1)
        view.expand(index)
        # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        # select last row
        selmod = view.selectionModel()
        index2 = model.indexFromItem(child3)
        selmod.select(index2, QItemSelectionModel.Select | QItemSelectionModel.Rows)


        layout.addWidget(view , 1, 0)
        self.setTabText(2, "Education Details")

        self.tab1.setLayout(layout)




def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = tabdemo()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: NB: if you have other questions, please [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `setIndexWidget` to set a widget on any column of a row:

```
class tabdemo(QTabWidget):
    ...
    def tab1UI(self):
        for i in range(3):
            parent1 = QStandardItem('Family {}. Some long status text for sp'.format(i))
            parent1.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(parent1)
            for j in range(3):
                child1 = QStandardItem('Child {}'.format(i * 3 + j))
                child2 = QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j + 1))
                child3 = QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j + 2))
                child4 = QStandardItem()
                parent1.appendRow([child1, child2, child3, child4])
                button = QToolButton()
                button.setMaximumSize(button.sizeHint())
                view.setIndexWidget(child4.index(), button)
```

Answer (score 2):

If by "button" you mean a simple image of a button at the beginning of each row , you may use `QStandardItem::setData(const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::UserRole + 1)` with role = `Qt::DecorationRole` and value being a `QIcon` or a `QPixmap`.

if you want a `QPushButton` for example, then you might consider building your custom delegate by inheriting `QStyledItemDelegate` and render a specific display of your model.

Answer (score 1):

`QStandardItemModel` is a model, it just contains data. The view and its delegate(s) handle the visualizations.

Maybe your use case it better served with a `QTreeWidget` and using its `setItemWidget()` feature